# Trouble installing Mercurial 1.5 on Mac OS X 10.5.8 (without using MacPorts)

Tags: macos, python, mercurial

I'm having trouble installing Mercurial 1.5 (build 20100307) from the prebuilt installer on Mac OS X 10.5.8 (2006 Core Duo MacBook Pro). The machine has never had the mac developer tools installed.

The installer is halting telling me that I need to install Python 2.6 to continue. I've installed the latest version of Python (2.6.5) twice now but it's not helping.

`which python` is reporting `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python`, but I can see that I also have 2.3 and 2.5 in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions` directory, which I suspect is being picked up by the installer ahead of the 2.6 install.

If possible I'd like to install Mercurial and Python without having to resort to [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts), but if that is the only option then so be it :)

Comment: I have Mercurial installed on Mac OS without MacPorts, so I at least know it's possible.  Can you provide any additional information? Where did you get the installer? Can you re-download the installer or change to a different installer distribution?

Comment: I used the following installers:

 - Mercurial: http://mercurial.berkwood.com/binaries/Mercurial-1.5-py2.6-macosx10.6.zip (via http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads/)
 - Python: http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.5/python-2.6.5-macosx10.3-2010-03-24.dmg (via http://www.python.org/download/).

As far as I can tell they're the default precompiled packages for the latest versions of both.

Going to try and redownload or try a different distribution next...

Comment: doh! just noticed that i'm using the 10.6 installer of mercurial, this is almost certainly the problem. going to download the correct installer now and will add an answer if this was the issue (yes, feeling silly)

Answer (score 1):

I was using the incorrect mercurial distribution (os x 10.6) when i should have been using the 10.5 distribution! Now resolved.